# Get_absolute_url with ForeignKey doesn't work in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to return JsonResponse in Django View:

```
return JsonResponse(render_to_string(
            'notifications/notifications_dropdown.html',
            {'new_notifications': new_notifications}),
            safe=False)
```

notifications_dropdown.html:

```
{% if new_notifications %}
    {% for notification in new_notifications %}
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ notification.task.get_absolute_url }}">
            <span class="text-success">
                <strong><i class="fas fa-info fa-fw"></i>{{ notification.title }}</strong>
            </span>
            <span class="small float-right text-muted">{{ notification.created|date:"SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT" }}</span>
            <div class="dropdown-message small">{{ notification.text }}</div>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

And my Notification Model has ForeignKey:

```
task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                             null=True)
```

The problem is that *{{ notification.task.get_absolute_url }}* returns nothing. But when I get the same notification object in shell, it returns correct url. Besides, I use *{{ task.get_absolute_url }}* in other templates, and it works as expected.

Any ideas, why *{{ notification.task.get_absolute_url }}* doesn't work in template?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had

```
new_notifications = Notification.objects.filter(
            user=request.user,
            status=Notification.NEW
        ).values()
```

And *.values()* didn't include task object. It just returned *task_id*